# OMNeT++ doesn't recognize nodes created by VACaMobil

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am starting to use VACaMobil in a project. However, I am having a problem. 
I don't know if I am wrong, but I understand that TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd
(ant therefore, VACaMobil) creates dynamically the nodes representing each vehicle, i. e.
 the car module isn't defined in the network file, but it's declared in the omnetpp.ini file, in 
parameters "**.manager.moduleType" and "**.manager.moduleName". In my case, the module
type is a custom car module based in the Car module of inet/examples/VACaMobil/Cars, and
the module name is "coche".

Here is the omnetpp.ini file:

```
    [General]

    network = Cars

    cmdenv-express-mode = true
    cmdenv-autoflush = true
    cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s
    repeat = 10
    tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins
    tkenv-image-path = bitmaps

    #sim-time-limit = 6000s

    check-signals = true

    **.manager.**.scalar-recording = true
    **.manager.**.vector-recording = true
    **.manetrouting.**.scalar-recording = true
    **.movStats.**.scalar-recording = true
    **.movStats.**.vector-recording = true
    **.mac.**.scalar-recording = true
    **.mac.**.vector-recording = true
    **.scalar-recording = true
    **.vector-recording = true

    *.channelControl.carrierFrequency = 2.4GHz
    *.channelControl.pMax = 2mW
    *.channelControl.sat = -110dBm
    *.channelControl.alpha = 2
    *.channelControl.numChannels = 1

    # TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd
    *.manager.updateInterval = 1s
    *.manager.host = "localhost"
    *.manager.port = 9999
    *.manager.moduleType = "rcdp9.TAdhocHost"
    *.manager.moduleName = "coche"
    *.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
    *.manager.autoShutdown = true
    *.manager.margin = 25
    *.manager.doNothing = false

    # nic settings
    **.wlan.bitrate = 24Mbps
    **.wlan.opMode = "g"
    **.wlan.mgmt.frameCapacity = 10
    **.wlan.mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc"
    **.wlan.mac.basicBitrate = 24Mbps
    **.wlan.mac.controlBitrate = 24Mbps
    **.wlan.mac.address = "auto"
    **.wlan.mac.maxQueueSize = 14
    **.wlan.mac.rtsThresholdBytes = 3000B
    **.wlan.mac.retryLimit = 7
    **.wlan.mac.cwMinData = 7
    **.wlan.radio.transmitterPower = 2mW
    **.wlan.radio.thermalNoise = -110dBm
    **.wlan.radio.sensitivity = -85dBm
    **.wlan.radio.pathLossAlpha = 2
    **.wlan.radio.snirThreshold = 4dB

    **.getStatistics = true
    **.statFiles = "${resultdir}/${configname}-${runnumber}-"

    **.channelNumber = 0

[Config RCDP]

**.coche[0..49].app1.localPort = 1000
**.coche[0..49].app1.destPort = 1000
**.coche[0..49].app1.messageLength = ${50000000B ! length}
**.coche[0..49].app1.burstSize = 10
**.coche[0..49].app1.bandWidth = 147200bps
**.coche[0..49].app1.alpha = 0.5
**.coche[0..49].app1.beta = 0.8
**.coche[0..49].app1.destAddresses = moduleListByPath("**.coche[50..99]")
**.coche[0..49].networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = "configurator"

**.coche[50..99].app2.localPort = 1000
**.coche[50..99].app2.messageLength = ${length = 50000000B}
**.coche[50..99].app2.bandWidth = 147200bps
**.coche[50..99].app2.maxBandWidth = 24Mbps

#**.meanNumberOfCars = ${100, 200, 300, 400}
**.meanNumberOfCars = 100
**.warmUpSeconds = 0s
**.autoShutdown = false
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("VACaMobil/Milan/downtown.launch.xml")

# manet routing
**.routingProtocol = ${"AODVUU", "DYMO", "OLSR"}

[Config TCP]

**.coche[0..49].app3.localPort = 1000
**.coche[0..49].app3.startTime = 0s
**.coche[0..49].app3.stopTime = 100s
**.coche[0..49].app3.thinkTime = 1s
**.coche[0..49].app3.idleInterval =3s
**.coche[0..49].app3.requestLength = 50000000B
**.coche[0..49].app3.numRequestsPerSession = 100
**.coche[0..49].app3.connectAddress = moduleListByPath("**.coche[50..99]")
**.coche[0..49].networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = "configurator"

**.coche[50..99].app4.dataTransferMode = "object"

#carGRCnator
**.getStatistics = true
**.statFiles = "${resultdir}/${configname}-${runnumber}-"

#**.meanNumberOfCars = ${100, 200, 300, 400}
**.meanNumberOfCars = 100
**.warmUpSeconds = 0s
**.autoShutdown = false
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("VACaMobil/Milan/downtown.launch.xml")

# manet routing
**.routingProtocol = ${"AODVUU", "DYMO", "OLSR"}
```

Here is the car module (TAdhocHost.ned):

```
package rcdp9;

import inet.base.NotificationBoard;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.HostAutoConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;
import inet.mobility.single.TraCIMobility;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTable;
import inet.transport.tcp.TCP;
import inet.transport.udp.UDP;
import inet.nodes.inet.NetworkLayer;
import inet.linklayer.ieee80211.Ieee80211Nic;
import inet.networklayer.IManetRouting;

module TAdhocHost
{
    parameters:
        @node();
        string routingProtocol @enum("AODVUU","DYMOUM","DYMO","DSRUU","OLSR","OLSR_ETX","DSDV_2","Batman") = default("");

    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;

    submodules:
        notificationBoard: NotificationBoard {
            parameters:
                @display("p=60,160");
        }
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=60,240");
        }
        app1: RCDPClient {
            parameters:
                @display("p=304,56");
        }
        app2: RCDPServer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=210,56");
        }
        app3: TCPClient {
            parameters:
                @display("p=378,56");
        }
        app4: TCPServer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=147,56");
        }
        mobility: TraCIMobility {
            parameters:
                @display("p=60,459");
        }
        routingTable: RoutingTable {
            parameters:
                IPForward = true;
                routerId = "";
                routingFile = "";
                @display("p=60,326");
        }
        udp: UDP {
            parameters:
                @display("p=304,192");
        }
        tcp: TCP {
            parameters:
                @display("p=219,192");
        }
        networkLayer: NetworkLayer {
            parameters:
                proxyARP = false;
                @display("p=304,327;q=queue");
            gates:
                ifIn[1];
                ifOut[1];
        }
        manetrouting: <routingProtocol> like IManetRouting if routingProtocol != "" {
            @display("p=522,307");
        }
        wlan: Ieee80211Nic {
            parameters:
                @display("p=304,461;q=queue");
        }
        ac_wlan: HostAutoConfigurator {
            @display("p=60,401");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        udp.appOut++ --> app1.udpIn;
        udp.appIn++ <-- app1.udpOut;

        udp.appOut++ --> app2.udpIn;
        udp.appIn++ <-- app2.udpOut;

        udp.ipOut --> networkLayer.transportIn++;
        udp.ipIn <-- networkLayer.transportOut++;

        tcp.appOut++ --> app3.tcpIn;
        tcp.appIn++ <-- app3.tcpOut;

        tcp.appOut++ --> app4.tcpIn;
        tcp.appIn++ <-- app4.tcpOut;

        tcp.ipOut --> networkLayer.transportIn++;
        tcp.ipIn <-- networkLayer.transportOut++;

        wlan.upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn[0];
        wlan.upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut[0];

        networkLayer.transportOut++ --> manetrouting.from_ip if routingProtocol != "";
        networkLayer.transportIn++ <-- manetrouting.to_ip if routingProtocol != "";

        radioIn --> wlan.radioIn;
}
```

Here is the network file (Cars.ned):

```
package rcdp9;

import inet.world.VACaMobil.VACaMobil;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.world.radio.ChannelControl;
import inet.world.traci.TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd;

network Cars
{
    submodules:
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
          @display("p=396,221");
        }
        channelControl: ChannelControl {
            @display("p=396,310");
        }
        manager: VACaMobil {
            @display("p=322,405");
        }
        connections allowunconnected:
}
```

The problem is that in the omnetpp.ini, OMNeT++ gives the following warning 
in lines beginning in "**.channelNumber", "**.wlan.", "**.coche", and "**.routingProtocol":
"Warning: Unused entry (does not match any parameters) Does not match any module parameters."
Apparently, OMNeT++ complains because the module TAdhocHost, whose name is "coche",
isn't defined in Cars.ned, but isn't assumed that OMNeT++ automatically recognizes that "coche"
is created by VACaMobil? I am doing something wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case (all modules are created via appropriate statements in a simulation's .ned files) the IDE can simply parse all .ned files to know what modules exist.

However, the Veins `TraCIScenarioManager`  directly uses the OMNeT++ C++ API to create additional modules at runtime. Before the simulation is run, the OMNeT++ IDE has no way of knowing that this will happen.

Without understanding what your C++ code does, it cannot know that the module parameters in your .ini file will (not at the start, but at a later point in the simulation) refer to a module that will exist.

There might be ways around this (declaring in a .ned  file that a module should not be created automatically, but can be assumed to exist anyway), but I don't recall any that is not a hack.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. I thought that OMNeT++ didn't recognizes the nodes created by VACaMobil, but I was wrong. I was checking my project, and the problem is that the nodes don't communicate through UDP or TCP, which is my goal.  For the first configuration I have two UDP apps (client and server) and for the second one two TCP apps (client and server). I have only seen examples with one UDP or TCP app. It's possible this? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to good questions. For this to work it's best not to mix multiple questions into one. What you are asking in your comment sounds different to your original question. If you don't mind, could you please ask this in a separate question?